# Golang: конвертирование формата json pointer в json

Tags: json, golang

Всем привет, у меня есть документ примерно такого вида в формате json pointer:

```
/g : true
/1 : false
/a~1b/0 : 1
/a~1b/1 : null
/a~1b/2/c/d : "e"
/a~1b/2/c/f : null
```

Мне нужно сконвертировать его в документ в виде стандартного json:

```
{
    "a/b":
    [
        1,
        null,
        {
            "c": 
            {
                "d": "e",
                "f": null
            }
        }
    ],
    "g": true,
    "1": false
}
```

Как можно лучше решить эту проблему? Может быть в Golang есть какие-нибудь стандартные средства или библиотеки для решения данной проблемы?

Comment: `map[*string]interface{}` - в помощь

Comment: У вас не может быть документ в формате JSON Pointer. Это физически невозможно - JP задаёт пути для извлечения значений из JSON документа. То,что есть у вас - спецификации путей и результаты соответствующих запросов к документу. Вам нужно, зная результаты запросов, сконструировать объект. Никаких стандартных инструментов для этого нет. Только ручками.

Comment: JSON Pointer - это что-то вроде XSLT для XML, и для него вполне есть и RFC, и библиотеки. Как пример, [1](https://github.com/qri-io/jsonpointer), [2](https://github.com/xeipuuv/gojsonpointer). Для использования данных выше вам нужен JSON документ, на котором их применять.